# Не получается передать данные из активности во фрагмент

Tags: android

при нажатии на кнопку getArgument возвращает null

В активити

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
GlobalMainActivity globalMainActivity = new GlobalMainActivity();
bundle.putString(KEY_FRAGMENT, "HELLO");
globalMainActivity.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(globalMainActivity, KEY_FRAGMENT);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Во фрагменте

```
String s = getArguments().getString(KEY_FRAGMENT);
```

Возможно еще проблема заключается во viewpager, но я не уверен

Comment: `GlobalMainActivity` это и есть ваш фрагмент? Мозг ломается от таких названий :)

Comment: Да, ну ничего лучше не придумал)

Comment: Что значит не получается? Какая ошибка? Где именно во фрагменте вы пытаетесь читать аргументы? И при чём здесь ViewPager?